# Converting Byte Array to String Using NumPy Dtype Only. Python

Tags: python, string, numpy

I'm working on a task where I need to convert a byte array obtained from a hexadecimal string into a string representation, utilizing only the specified data type (dtype) in NumPy. Here's what I've tried:

```
import numpy as np

# Define the data type as a Unicode string of length 1
dt = np.dtype('<S1')  # Unicode string of length 1

# Sample data
res = '52'

# Convert the hexadecimal string to a bytearray
buf = bytearray.fromhex(res)

# Create a NumPy array from the list of characters
arr_resp = np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=dt)

print(arr_resp_str)
```

the consol:

```
[b'R']
```

and I want to store it as:

```
['R']
```

However, instead of obtaining the string representation of the byte array, the output displays the characters as byte class objects. How can I adjust this code to achieve the string representation using only the NumPy dtype?
**I don't want to just convert, (like DECODE etc.) but store back the string inside a NUMPY object**
Your insights and suggestions would be invaluable. Thank you.

Comment: Use slice `print(arr_resp_str[0:])`

Comment: I don't want to just convert, (like DECODE etc.) I want store back the string inside a NUMPY object

Comment: `np.dtype('<S1')` is not unicode.  It's one byte. 'U1' is unicode, 4 bytes. (technically unicode is 1-4 bytes, but numpy has to have a consistent `itemsize!. `np.array([b'R']).astype('U1')` should do  the desired conversion (but probably using string methods under the covers).

Comment: `b'R'` is how python3 displays a byte string.  That used to be the standard in python2.  Now the default is unicode, which is displayed as `'R'` (or `u'R'`).

Comment: I don't understand this: `store back the string inside a NUMPY object`.  The buffer contains one byte, which can be interpreted as 'uint8' or 'S1'.  It'can't be a 'U1' character without `decode`.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [63]: res = '52'
    ...: 
    ...: # Convert the hexadecimal string to a bytearray
    ...: buf = bytearray.fromhex(res)
```

So you have created a bytearray with one ASCII character:

```
In [64]: buf
Out[64]: bytearray(b'R')
```

That can be read with 'S1':

```
In [65]: np.frombuffer(buf, dtype='S1')
Out[65]: array([b'R'], dtype='|S1')
```

but not with 'U1' (unicode):

```
In [66]: np.frombuffer(buf, dtype='U1')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[66], line 1
----> 1 np.frombuffer(buf, dtype='U1')

ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size
```

`astype` can convert the 'S1' to 'U1':

```
In [67]: np.frombuffer(buf, dtype='S1').astype('U1')
Out[67]: array(['R'], dtype='<U1')

In [68]: _.itemsize
Out[68]: 4
```

Under the covers I'm pretty sure numpy is using the python string decode.  `numpy` doesn't have much of its own 'raw' string code; it uses python's.

```
In [70]: np.frombuffer(buf, dtype='S1').item()
Out[70]: b'R'

In [71]: np.frombuffer(buf, dtype='S1').item().decode()
Out[71]: 'R'
```

edit

---

Let's look at what kinds of bytearrays `b'R'` and `'R'` produce:

```
In [166]: np.array([b'R']).tobytes()
Out[166]: b'R'

In [167]: bytearray(_)
Out[167]: bytearray(b'R')

In [168]: np.array(['R']).tobytes()
Out[168]: b'R\x00\x00\x00'

In [169]: bytearray(_)
Out[169]: bytearray(b'R\x00\x00\x00')
```

And applying `frombuffer` to these bytearrays:

```
In [170]: np.frombuffer(_,'U1')
Out[170]: array(['R'], dtype='<U1')

In [171]: np.frombuffer(__,'S1')
Out[171]: array([b'R', b'', b'', b''], dtype='|S1')
```

I suppose you could take the single byte array, add the 3 padding blanks, and 'read' that as 'U1'.  That would, in sense, do the `decode` without using the python method .